# UIColor colorWithPatternImage: transparency issues in UITableView's separatorColor

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, ios5, uicolor

I have troubles with setting my patterned `UIColor`. In iOS 5 it's all good, but in iOS 4.3 I get the issue. I added an image for better understanding. I already Googled a bit, and found that the answer is possibly the setting of the `opaque` property to `NO`. But I already set every `view`, `contentView`, `backgroundView`, `tableViewCell` it's `opaque` value to `NO`.

[image: You can see that the separator color is black, where the image has of the pattern has transparency]

You can see that the separator color is black, where the image has of the pattern has transparency

Comment: Same issue, did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Not yet. Removing the separators and setting a UIView as separator that is opaque, with the correct backgroundColor, works.

Answer (score 18):

This appears to be a bug in iOS 4.3 that they fixed in 5.0 .

To get this to work on 4.3, you'll need to set **both the view and the layer** to non-opaque, after setting the view's backgroundColor to the pattern image, like so:

```
UIImage* pattern = [UIImage imageNamed:@"translucentPatternImage.png"];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:pattern];
[view.layer setOpaque:NO];
view.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: Be sure to set the layer to non-opaque *after* you set the background color for this to work

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you have to set the background color of the labels in the TableViewCell. So something like,

[cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: It's not the gray boxes that bother me, I've set these to mask the contents ;)

Comment: Lol. D'oh sorry about that! Are you looking to remove the separator color?

Comment: As you can see on the top, the seperator color is transparent on the left and right 10 pixels. At the other two separators, this transparency turns black. This I don't have on iOS 5, only iOS 4.